# Get full Java stack trace from IBM Bluemix using logstash 2.3.4

Tags: java, log4j, cloud, logstash, ibm-cloud

I am very new to IBM Bluemix and Logstash.

My application is based on **Spring Boot + Log4j** which was deployed into **IBM BlueMix**.

**Goal:**

Reading **entire java stack trace + BlueMix log** and write into a **file** in **local** Linux Server.

I **don't** want to use **elastic search & Kibana**. I think it is **overkill** for my requirement. I don't want fancy GUI thing, but a basic text file which contains all log information.

**What I did till now:**

1. Installed & Setup logstash.
2. Able to write bluemix log into a file in my local server.

Below is my **Logstash conf** file. **As I want entire** log, I am not using any filter. (based on my 1 day old logstash knowledge)

```
input {
    tcp {
        port => 5000
        type => syslog
    }
}
filter {

}
output {
      file {
        path => "/app/uot0/cloud/logstash/logstash-2.3.4/tmp/access_log"
   }
}
```

**Problem:**

Logstash output file "access_log" is **NOT** containing **full** stack trace from a Java Exception, it contains only **name of that exception**.

(part of) **Original log from BlueMix console:**

```
 2016-07-15T19:31:34.184-0400[App/0]OUT23:31:34.183 [36m[http-nio-61430-exec-10][0;39m [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver[0;39m [30m- Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> com.abc.xyx.rest.TaskController.getTasks(org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest)]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid enum name:Other in com.abc.xyx.service.task.TaskType
2016-07-15T19:31:34.187-0400[App/0]OUT[0;39m23:31:34.186 [36m[http-nio-61430-exec-10][0;39m [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36mo.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory[0;39m [30m- Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'exceptionHandlingAdvice'
2016-07-15T19:31:34.189-0400[App/0]OUT[0;39m23:31:34.189 [36m[http-nio-61430-exec-10][0;39m [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver[0;39m [30m- Invoking @ExceptionHandler method: public void com.abc.xyx.rest.ExceptionHandlingAdvice.systemException(java.lang.Exception)
2016-07-15T19:31:34.193-0400[App/0]OUT[0;39m23:31:34.192 [36m[http-nio-61430-exec-10][0;39m [1;31mERROR[0;39m [36mc.r.t.r.ExceptionHandlingAdvice[0;39m [30m- Unexpected system exception
2016-07-15T19:31:34.193-0400[App/0]OUT[0;39mjava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid enum name:Other in com.abc.xyx.service.task.TaskType
2016-07-15T19:31:34.194-0400[App/0]OUT at com.abc.xyx.service.task.TaskUtils.getEnum(TaskUtils.java:30) ~[xyx-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
2016-07-15T19:31:34.194-0400[App/0]OUT at com.abc.xyx.service.task.Task.init(Task.java:179) ~[xyx-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
2016-07-15T19:31:34.194-0400[App/0]OUT at com.abc.xyx.service.task.TaskService.searchOnePageTasks(TaskService.java:558) ~[xyx-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
2016-07-15T19:31:34.194-0400[App/0]OUT at com.abc.xyx.service.task.Task.<init>(Task.java:93) ~[xyx-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
2016-07-15T19:31:34.194-0400[App/0]OUT at com.abc.xyx.service.task.TaskService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$bb02ea04.invoke(<generated>) ~[xyx-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
2016-07-15T19:31:34.194-0400[App/0]OUT at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
```

(entire) **Equivalent log** which was written into access.log by **logstash** is below:

```
{"message":"549 <14>1 2016-07-15T23:31:34.208666+00:00 loggregator c022c216-4373-418e-bb4d-fbde0b41d720 [App/0] - - \u001B[0;39m23:31:34.208 \u001B[36m[http-nio-61430-exec-10]\u001B[0;39m \u001B[39mDEBUG\u001B[0;39m \u001B[36mo.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor\u001B[0;39m \u001B[30m- Written [{timestamp=Fri Jul 15 23:31:34 UTC 2016, status=500, error=Internal Server Error, exception=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException, message=System exception, path=/api/tasksearch}] as \"application/json;charset=UTF-8\" using
```

**Question:**

How can I get the full stack trace for Java Exceptions, so that it will be useful for debugging?

Any help will be appreciated...